# Lebesgue integral calculation help

Tags: integration, measure-theory, limits

I have this limit to evaluate $$\lim\nolimits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{2} \arctan \left(\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right) dx.$$

I have no idea how to solve this homework problem. Help!

Comment: HINT: Can you find a function which dominates $\arctan \left(\frac1{1+x^n} \right)$?. Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \arctan \left(\frac1{1+x^n} \right)$ and then use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to swap the limit and the integral.

Comment: What did you try? Where did it go wrong? You will not learn without trying.

Comment: @AD. I don't have any clue. I was thinking about integration by parts type of techniques...TT

Comment: No, integration by parts is not the way.  Try the hint already given in a comment.

Comment: So for x between 0 and 1, the $\lim_{n ->\infty} \arctan(\frac{1}{1+x^n})$ is $\arctan 1$, which is $\pi/4$. for x between 1 and 2, it's $\arctan 0$, which is 0?

Comment: If I should be picky you there are three cases/limits...

Comment: three cases? oh when x=1!

Comment: @TaoleZ Right! But it does not matter in the situation :)

Comment: When you think about Lebesgue integrals, think about convergence theorems.

Comment: Anytime you have a limit and a Lebesgue integral your mind should involuntarily think "this requires a convergence theorem!"

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$\arctan$ is bounded.